# There is no READABLE property named 'first_name' in class 'Employee'

Tags: java, ibatis

I am new to ibatis,

i have written a small program in ibatis.

But i'm getting the below error. I tried in all way. I'm unaware of that how to resolve.

Could anyone tell me why this is occurring and whats the way to avoid this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibatis.common.exception.NestedRuntimeException: Error occurred.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.exception.NestedRuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMapConfig/sqlMap'.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.xml.NodeletException: Error parsing XML.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.exception.NestedRuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMap/update'.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named 'first_name' in class 'Employee'
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named 'first_name' in class 'Employee'
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.exception.NestedRuntimeException: Error parsing XPath '/sqlMap/update'.  Cause: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named 'first_name' in class 'Employee'
Caused by: com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named 'first_name' in class 'Employee'
Caused by: 
com.ibatis.common.beans.ProbeException: There is no READABLE property named 'first_name' in class 'Employee'
```

Code:
Employee.java  it contains getter and setter methods for first_name,last_name,id,salary

employeedao.java

```
public static void main()
{
Reader rd=Resources.getResourceAsReader("sql-maps-config.xml");
SqlMapClient smc = SqlMapClientBuilder.buildSqlMapClient(rd);
System.out.println("Going to read records.....");
 rec.setId(1);
           rec.setFirstName("Roma");
           smc.update("UserTEO.update", rec );
           System.out.println("Record updated Successfully ");

           System.out.println("Going to read records.....");
 List <employeedao> ems = (List<employeedao>)
           smc.queryForList("UserTEO.getAll", null);
           employeedao em = null;
           for (employedao e : ems) {
              System.out.print("  " + e.getId());
             // System.out.print("  " + e.getFirstName());
           //   System.out.print("  " + e.getLastName());
              System.out.print("  " + e.getSalary());
              em = e; 
              System.out.println("");
           }    

       System.out.println("Records Read Successfully ");
}
```

employee.xml

```
 <select id="getAll" resultClass="Employee">
   SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE
</select>

<update id="update" parameterClass="Employee">
   UPDATE EMPLOYEE
   SET    first_name = #first_name#
   WHERE  id = #id#
</update>

</sqlMap>
```

Comment: Post some code and we can help you.

Comment: Added my code in my above comment itself. Please look at that

Comment: The message says: "there is no readable property "first_name" in class Employee". So, where's the code of the class Employee? And why don't you respect the Java naming conventions?

Comment: i have the below code for first_name in Employee.java            private String first_name;                                          public String getFirstName() {
    return first_name;
  }
  public void setFirstName(String fname) {
    this.first_name = fname;
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The getter is

```
public String getFirstName()
```

So, the property is `firstName`, not `first_name`.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html

Comment: Thanks Nizet. cleared the problem by changing public string getfirstname() { return firstname; }

Comment: Don't do that. Respect the Java naming conventions. The field should be named "firstName". The getter should be named "getFirstName()". The property will thus be "firstName".